# Mongodb: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb

I want to start a configuration node in a remote server，But when I start a mongod process, I cannot open it with mongo command。Can't even open on the local node。

```
root@Ubuntu04:~/mongodb# mongod --configsvr --replSet mongoConfig --dbpath config2/data --bind_ip [localhost,master] --port 21000 --logpath config2/log/config.log --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 833
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

```
root@Ubuntu04:~/mongodb# mongo localhost:21000
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:21000/test?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-27T17:15:23.552+0800 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:21000, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:21000 (127.0.0.1:21000) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-27T17:15:23.555+0800 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-27T17:15:23.555+0800 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Maybe you should write a [config file](Configuration File Options) and start like `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. Try to start without `--fork` option, then the you may see more. Have a log at the logfile

Comment: The files are relative file names, i.e. `~/config2/data` and `~/config2/log/config.log` -> since you are root, most likely the mongod user cannot access the files.